# Concatenate two strings

Tags: beginner, c, strings

I am learning C and wrote a function to concatenate two strings in C. Please let help me improve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void concat (char result[], const char str1[], int n1, const char str2[], int n2)
{
    int i, j;
    // copy str1 to result
    for ( i = 0; i < n1; ++i )
        result[i] = str1[i];

    // copy str2 to result
    for ( j = 0; j < n2; ++j )
        result[n1 + j] = str2[j];
}
int main (void)
{

    const char s1[5] = { 'T', 'e', 's', 't', ' '};
    const char s2[6] = { 'w', 'o', 'r', 'k', 's', '.' };
    char s3[11];

    int i;
    concat (s3, s1, 5, s2, 6);

    for ( i = 0; i < 11; ++i )
        printf ("%c", s3[i]);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you know about the `strcat()` function in the standard library, so I'm tagging this as such.  Please remove that if this assumption is false.

Comment: @syb0rg no, I didn't. But now I do?

Comment: You learn something new every day ;)

Comment: If you know `strcat()`, you should also know `strncat()`.

Comment: [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] is for when someone wants to indicate that they don't want to be told about the existing library function to perform the task.  It should only be added by the original poster.  It allows people to deliberately implement something unnecessary.  It should not be used by someone else if the poster does not know about the library function.  It's inappropriate here, as most of the answers are of the form, "You could have just used `strncat`."  Such answers would be invalid on a reinventing-the-wheel question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks pretty good!  A few notes (some stuff you may still have to learn about since you are a [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner), such as pointers)

- Your method isn't what I would consider "normal".  To see what I
  mean, take a look at the function prototype of the standard library
  function `strcat()`:

  ```
  char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
  ```

  As you can see, the standard library only takes in two parameters,
  not 5.  This makes sense too: as the caller I want to throw in two strings and only get one returned back to me.  For a string concatenation function, I shouldn't have to manually enter in the length of the strings I want to concatenate, the function should be able to handle that.
- So how do we find the length of a string exactly?  Well, we can iterate through a string until we find the `\0` character (termination character).

  ```
  while(*dest != '\0') /* find the end of the string */
  {
       dest++;
  }
  ```

  All this loop does it start at the beginning of the `dest` string and find the end of it, very simple.  The next loop is a bit more complicated:

  ```
  while((*dest++ = *source++) != '\0'); /* copy source */
  ```

  This code iterates through the `source` string, and while it iterates through it, it appends the contents to `dest` (which we are doing by iterating `dest` at the same time as `source`).  We do this until we reach the `\0` character.
- We should be returning a value from the function.  This is more for a convenience to the caller.  This allows me to do stuff such as

  ```
  puts(concat(strdup("test"), "this out"));
  ```

  Rather than this longer piece:

  ```
  char* str = strdup("test");
  concat(str, "test");
  puts(str);
  ```
- `strcat` can be dangerous because if the string to be appended is too long to fit in the destination buffer, it will overwrite adjacent memory, invoking undefined behavior. Usually the program will simply cause a segmentation fault when this occurs, but a skilled attacker can use such a buffer overflow to break into a system.

  To prevent buffer overflows, several alternatives for `strcat()` have been used. All of them take an extra argument which encodes the length of the destination buffer and will not write past that buffer end. All of them can still result in buffer overflows if an incorrect length is provided.

  ```
  char* strncat(char *dst, const char *src, size_t n);
  ```

  This will require a bit of modification to the copying for checking `n`, but not much.

---

#### Final Implementation (assuming no standard library functions can be used):

```
char* concat_s(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
{
    if (n != 0) // if n == 0 then we aren't concatenating anything... 
    {
        while (*dest != 0)
        {
            dest++;
        }
        do 
        {
            if (0 == (*dest = *src++)) break;
            dest++;
        } while (--n != 0);
        *dest = 0;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

#### Final Implementation (assuming all functions can be used except `strncat()`):

```
char* concat_s(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
{
    return memcpy(dest + strlen(dest), src, n);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be a bad idea also presenting a "safer" version that takes a max size for `dest`. (`strncat`)

Comment: @glampert I was just working on making an edit for that.  Please hold :P

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very thorough. Other answers were helpful too, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to declare `#include <string.h>` in your program as it is.

You can improve your `concat()` function by changing the `for` loops so they can work on variable-length character strings. ie strings with different lengths, not just `5` and `6`. Note you are testing for the `null`-terminator which is `\0`

```
for ( i = 0; i < str1[i] != '\0'; ++i )
    result[i] = str1[i];
```

Generally, you will probably just need to call `strcpy()` and `strcat()`. In this case, you will need `#include <string.h>`

```
strcpy(s3,s1);
strcat(s3,s2);
```

Instead of using a `for` loop to output `s3` , do:

```
printf("%s\n",s3);
```

Your whole program will be much smaller:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (void)
{

    const char s1[] = { "Test " };
    const char s2[] = { "works." };
    char s3[11];

    strcpy(s3,s1);
    strcat(s3,s2);
    printf("%s\n",s3);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not terribly familiar with C, so perhaps other reviews will offer more useful info. However, using library functions is preferred.

Comment: Is this a bad review (the downvote)? I will gladly improve my answer on feedback.

Comment: I didn't down vote you. In part because I am no C expert. But it appears that the strings are not null terminated and I believe this makes `strcopy` and `strcat` poor choices. My perhaps mistaken understanding [based on Plauger's *The Standard C Library*] is that `memcopy` into a new array of type `char`, is safer. Of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: @benrudgers Thanks! I improved my answer. My bad. I forgot to change how the character strings were initialized. I thought `strncpy`, the "safer" version of `strcpy` had issues of it's own.

Comment: Again no expert but I think `strncopy` will struggle if the string contains non-terminating null characters. So it's really a question of what "safe" means. To me, once you've got strings without null terminators, other assumptions about null become more doubtful.

Answer (score 3):

### Interface

You use `const` for `str1` and `str2`, which is good.

For `n1` and `n2`, it is customary to use `size_t` as the type, as a hint to other programmers that those are array sizes.  Using `int` isn't wrong, though.

I suggest returning `result` for the caller's convenience.

The purpose of the function is either confused or falsely advertised.  C strings are customarily terminated with a null character (`'\0'`).  If you name your parameter `str…`, then I would expect that it relies on such null terminators.  On the other hand, you also require the lengths `n1` and `n2` to be explicitly provided.  That looks like more of a memory-copying operation than a string-concatenating operation.

> Side note: When some parts of a system work with null-terminated strings, while other parts work with strings of explicit lengths (and which may contain null characters as valid data), the mismatch tends to cause a whole class of bugs, some of which have [security implications](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040824-00/?p=38063).

### `main()`

Printing a character at a time is unusual and tedious.  A call to `printf("%.11s\n")` would be much more convenient than looping.

If you wanted to print a character at a time anyway, then `putchar()` would be a simpler function to call.

### Implementation of `concat()`

Declare variables in the tightest scope possible, as late as possible.  To another programmer encountering your code, the `int i, j` declaration at the top is meaningless.  On the other hand,

```
for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
```

makes it clear that `i` is a counter that is only used in that loop.

Always write your blocks and loops with the optional braces.  By omitting the braces, you are contributing to a future [coding accident](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html).

Comment: Opie may or may not be using a C99+ compiler.

Comment: @DavidConrad The code has C99-style comments. Might as well go all the way. Besides, it's 2014 — that's 15 years since C99!